# Inno Setup failing to install and falls over on the x86 executable

Tags: inno-setup

I have an unusual problem on some of my users computers when they try to run my upgrade. It is inno-setup based.

The issue is specific to my x86 executable file. The error they get when they run the installer in admin mode is:

[image: Error 1]

If I click Ignore it continues and I eventually get another error:

[image: Error 2]

During this install I was using the log via the command line and this was the results:

```
2017-02-20 09:20:56.138   Log opened. (Time zone: UTC+00:00)
2017-02-20 09:20:56.138   Setup version: Inno Setup version 5.5.9 (u)
2017-02-20 09:20:56.138   Original Setup EXE: C:\Users\David Hopkins\Desktop\MeetSchedAssistSetup.exe
2017-02-20 09:20:56.138   Setup command line: /SL5="$CB062C,6981002,121344,C:\Users\David Hopkins\Desktop\MeetSchedAssistSetup.exe" /log=.\InstallMSALog.txt
2017-02-20 09:20:56.138   Windows version: 10.0.14393  (NT platform: Yes)
2017-02-20 09:20:56.139   64-bit Windows: Yes
2017-02-20 09:20:56.139   Processor architecture: x64
2017-02-20 09:20:56.139   User privileges: Administrative
2017-02-20 09:20:56.148   64-bit install mode: No
2017-02-20 09:20:59.225   Created temporary directory: C:\Users\DAVIDH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\is-U020O.tmp
2017-02-20 09:20:59.239   Extracting temporary file: C:\Users\DAVIDH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\is-U020O.tmp\isxdl.dll
2017-02-20 09:21:00.119   Windows Version: A003839
2017-02-20 09:21:06.324   Starting the installation process.
2017-02-20 09:21:06.338   Directory for uninstall files: C:\Program Files (x86)\Meeting Schedule Assistant
2017-02-20 09:21:06.340   Will append to existing uninstall log: C:\Program Files (x86)\Meeting Schedule Assistant\unins000.dat
2017-02-20 09:21:06.348   -- File entry --
2017-02-20 09:21:06.349   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Meeting Schedule Assistant\unins000.exe
2017-02-20 09:21:06.352   Time stamp of our file: 2017-02-20 09:20:55.971
2017-02-20 09:21:06.352   Dest file exists.
2017-02-20 09:21:06.352   Time stamp of existing file: 2017-02-20 06:50:42.931
2017-02-20 09:21:06.353   Version of our file: 51.1052.0.0
2017-02-20 09:21:06.353   Version of existing file: 51.1052.0.0
2017-02-20 09:21:06.353   Installing the file.
2017-02-20 09:21:06.418   Uninstaller requires administrator: Yes
2017-02-20 09:21:06.426   Leaving temporary file in place for now.
2017-02-20 09:21:06.428   -- File entry --
2017-02-20 09:21:06.429   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Meeting Schedule Assistant\MeetSchedAssist.exe
2017-02-20 09:21:06.430   Time stamp of our file: 2017-02-19 20:41:08.000
2017-02-20 09:21:06.430   Installing the file.
2017-02-20 09:21:09.364   MoveFile: The existing file appears to be in use (5). Retrying.
2017-02-20 09:21:10.366   MoveFile: The existing file appears to be in use (5). Retrying.
2017-02-20 09:21:11.367   MoveFile: The existing file appears to be in use (5). Retrying.
2017-02-20 09:21:14.841   MoveFile: The existing file appears to be in use (5). Retrying.
2017-02-20 09:21:15.842   Message box (Abort/Retry/Ignore):
                          C:\Program Files (x86)\Meeting Schedule Assistant\MeetSchedAssist.exe

                          An error occurred while trying to rename a file in the destination directory:
                          MoveFile failed; code 5.
                          Access is denied.

                          Click Retry to try again, Ignore to skip this file (not recommended), or Abort to cancel installation.
2017-02-20 09:21:51.492   User chose Ignore.
[SNIPPED]
2017-02-20 09:21:54.432   Dest filename: C:\Users\David Hopkins\Desktop\Meeting Schedule Assistant.lnk
2017-02-20 09:21:54.435   Creating the icon.
2017-02-20 09:21:54.461   Exception message:
2017-02-20 09:21:54.461   Message box (OK):
                          IPersistFile::Save failed; code 0x80070005.
                          Access is denied.
2017-02-20 09:22:13.536   User chose OK.
2017-02-20 09:22:13.654   Installation process succeeded.
2017-02-20 09:22:13.674   -- Run entry --
2017-02-20 09:22:13.674   Run as: Current user
2017-02-20 09:22:13.674   Type: Exec
2017-02-20 09:22:13.674   Filename: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe
2017-02-20 09:22:13.674   Parameters: PTSTools.dll /codebase
2017-02-20 09:22:14.009   Process exit code: 100
2017-02-20 09:22:14.009   -- Run entry --
2017-02-20 09:22:14.009   Run as: Current user
2017-02-20 09:22:14.009   Type: Exec
2017-02-20 09:22:14.009   Filename: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe
2017-02-20 09:22:14.009   Parameters: PTSTools.dll /codebase
2017-02-20 09:22:14.370   Process exit code: 0
2017-02-20 09:22:14.370   -- Run entry --
2017-02-20 09:22:14.370   Run as: Current user
2017-02-20 09:22:14.371   Type: Exec
2017-02-20 09:22:14.371   Filename: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe
2017-02-20 09:22:14.371   Parameters: MSAToolsLibrary_x86.dll /codebase
2017-02-20 09:22:14.583   Process exit code: 0
2017-02-20 09:22:14.583   -- Run entry --
2017-02-20 09:22:14.583   Run as: Current user
2017-02-20 09:22:14.583   Type: Exec
2017-02-20 09:22:14.584   Filename: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe
2017-02-20 09:22:14.584   Parameters: MSAToolsLibrary_x64.dll /codebase
2017-02-20 09:22:14.775   Process exit code: 0
2017-02-20 09:22:14.778   Need to restart Windows? No
2017-02-20 09:22:21.328   -- Run entry --
2017-02-20 09:22:21.328   Run as: Original user
2017-02-20 09:22:21.328   Type: Exec
2017-02-20 09:22:21.328   Filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Meeting Schedule Assistant\MeetSchedAssist_x64.exe
2017-02-20 09:22:22.330   Deinitializing Setup.
2017-02-20 09:22:22.427   Log closed.
```

You can see that it thinks the file is already in use.

The script is quite basic for the file concerned:

```
[Files]
Source: "Meeting Schedule Assistant.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; DestName: "MeetSchedAssist.exe"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "..\x64\Release\Meeting Schedule Assistant.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; DestName: "MeetSchedAssist_x64.exe"; Flags: ignoreversion
```

What to do?

Comment: *"You can see that it thinks the file is already in use"* - And is it? Did you check? Can you rename the file manually before you start the installation?

Comment: He did not have the software running. When it happened to another user there was nothing in the task list.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl The other thing is my app uses a mutex. So the system would handle it gracefully. Something else is locking it even though it is not running.

Comment: That's not conclusive enough. Again, can you rename the file manually before you start the installation?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I am no longer connected to his computer. I am not sure what time zone he is on. If this happens again I will try to rename the file. But if it can't be renamed, what then?

Comment: Then your question has nothing to do with Inno Setup. And you will have a chance to find out, what is having the file locked.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl OK, thank you.